# WiFi speed slower than reported by router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, dsl

I have an old DSL connection (pending fiber upgrade, hopefully...) that is giving me some awful 0.5mbps download speed.

However, if I log in to the router it reports ~20mbps download speed. This is definitely *not* what I get from a speedtest and not my browsing speed. (See screenshot below.)

I tried the obvious:
a) Restarting router;
b) Clearing browser cache;
c) Complaining with my ISP (they said they did some maintenance but I don't see any effect...);
d) Changing channel from inside my router;
e) Changing my DNS to Google DNS.

...to no avail.

Do you think my router is misreporting or...?

[image]

Comment: Could be that your router is too close to the system, also, if you have mirrors, refrigerators, microwave oven, etc. close by or running this may cause disturbances. Also be can be certain lightning fixtures may be causing interferences.

Comment: I'll try with ethernet

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to detect this

Enable Wifi on your router and connect any android device
and run 3rd party speed test fast.com

Then after above test finished check the speed test device connected
with dsl by above website

Compare the two results

Note:fast.com is 3rd party speed test used to check speed test

IF wifi speed slow than dsl by large extent wire faulty else
if both are similar then its good

But if above results dont match with router there may be error
with reporting